# SQLite file not updated once created with Core Data after changing Core Data Stack

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, save, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I changed my existing core stack and my sqlite file doesn't get updated anymore after it's created. I'm able to save and fetch data with core data, but the sqlite file is always empty(the sqlite-shm file gets updated instead). Is my implementation wrong? What do I need to do to get my sqlite file to be updated?

//header file

```
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *masterManagedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *mainManagedObjectContext;

-(NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator;
-(NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel;
-(NSManagedObjectContext *)masterManagedObjectContext;
-(NSManagedObjectContext *)mainManagedObjectContext;
-(NSManagedObjectContext *)workerManagedObjectContext;
```

//implementation file

```
@synthesize managedObjectModel = __managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = __persistentStoreCoordinator;
@synthesize masterManagedObjectContext = __masterManagedObjectContext;
@synthesize mainManagedObjectContext = __mainManagedObjectContext;



//Managed object context
-(NSManagedObjectContext *)masterManagedObjectContext{
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        __masterManagedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
        [__masterManagedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return __masterManagedObjectContext;
}

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)mainManagedObjectContext {
    if (__mainManagedObjectContext != nil) {
        return __mainManagedObjectContext;
    }

    __mainManagedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    [__mainManagedObjectContext setParentContext:self.masterManagedObjectContext];
    return __mainManagedObjectContext;
}

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)workerManagedObjectContext {

    NSManagedObjectContext *tempMOContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    tempMOContext.parentContext = [self mainManagedObjectContext];
    return tempMOContext;
}

//Save methods

- (void)saveWorkerContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context {
    NSError *error;
    [context save:&error];
    if (!error) {
    [self saveMainContext];
    }
}

- (void)saveMainContext {
    [self.mainManagedObjectContext performBlock:^{
        NSError *error = nil;
        [self.mainManagedObjectContext save:&error];
        if(!error){
            //Write to disk after saving on the main UI context
            [self saveMasterContext];
        }
    }];
}

- (void)saveMasterContext {

    [self.masterManagedObjectContext performBlock:^{
        NSError *error = nil;
        [self.masterManagedObjectContext save:&error];
        if(error){
            NSLog(@"CORE DATA MASTER CONTEXT ERROR : %@", error);
        }
    }];
}

-(NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {
    if (__managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return __managedObjectModel;
    }

    NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyResource"
                                                       ofType:@"bundle"];

    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:bundlePath];
    NSString *modelPath = [bundle pathForResource:@"MyData"
                                       ofType:@"momd"];
    //NSLog(@"Bundle modelURL:%@",modelPath);
    NSURL *modelURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:modelPath];
    __managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc]     initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return __managedObjectModel;
}


-(NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {
    if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyData.sqlite"];
    //NSLog(@"storeURL:%@",storeURL);
    NSError *error = nil;
    __persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}
```

//example of trying to save data

```
-(void)saveDictionary:(NSMutableDictionary *)myDictionary{

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self workerManagedObjectContext];
    [context performBlockAndWait:^{

        NSMutableDictionary *tmpDic = myDictionary;
        NSError *error;
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Entity"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:context];

        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
        NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

        Entity *myEntity;

        if ([fetchedObjects count]>0) {
            myEntity = [fetchedObjects lastObject];
        }
        else{
            myEntity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Entity" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        }

        myEntity.value = tmpDic[@"value1"]!=nil?tmpDic[@"value1"]:@"nothing";


        [self saveWorkerContext:context];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> What do I need to do to get this to work?

But you also said

> I'm able to save and fetch data with core data...

That's the definition of "working" with Core Data. If that works, you're done.

The SQLite shm file is the SQLite journal. It's an implementation detail of how SQLite works. You can read up on [how SQLite manages its files](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#rollbackjournal) if you're interested but it's not really relevant to what you're doing.

Comment: Maybe I should change my question from "What do I need to do to get this to work?" to "What do I need to do to get my sqlite file to be updated?" to be more clear?

Comment: Why do you want it to be updated? What's wrong with letting SQLite use its journal file, like it wants to? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @TomHarrington simply for testing for example migration process. I am having the same issue. I need to pre-populate my store.

Answer (score 0):

Simply for the time you want to generate sqlite file use the following options when you add persistent store:

`@{NSSQLitePragmasOption: @{@"journal_mode": @"DELETE"}}`

```
[persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil
                                                            URL:self.localStoreURL
                                                        options:@{NSSQLitePragmasOption: @{@"journal_mode": @"DELETE"}}
                                                          error:nil];
```

Then run the application, quit, go to the application folder and in `Documents` your file will be updated. I hope this will help you.